# Previous value in loop in Numba

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numba

I'm looping through an array out of order using an index array (or list), but for one of my calculations, I need the value of the previous point in the array (or list). I need to do this using the noPython mode for performance reasons.

For example:

```
ordered_pts = [0, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]
start = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]


@jit(nogil=True, nopython=True)
def loop_in_order(ordered_pts, start):
    for pt in ordered_pts:
        if start[pt]:
            prev_pt = None
        else:
            prev_pt = ordered_points[ordered_points.index(pt) - 1]
        print pt, prev_pt
```

While this function works when nonjitted, I get a cannot convert native?int64 to Python object error.

Is there an efficient way of getting the previous item in the list while still using noPython mode in numba? Or should I just feed my numba function a list of previous indices in addition to my current ones?

In addition, I'd prefer to keep my data types as arrays if possible. (I know the .index function is for lists, rather than arrays)

Answer (score 1):

`index` trigg quadratic complexity, where a quasi linear Numpy solution exists :

```
def numpy_loop_in_order(ordered_pts,start):        
    prev_pt=np.roll(ordered_pts,1)               # roll indices
    prev_pt[np.argsort(ordered_pts)[np.where(start)]] =-1  # see below
    return prev_pt
#[-1,  0,  1,  6,  2, -1,  7,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10]
```

I added a element to start an replace `None` by `-1` because Numpy arrays must be homogeneous. `np.argsort` find the index of all values in `O( n ln(n) )` , `np.where` determines which values will be set.

Furthermore Numba only accelerate code on np.arrays, not lists. And generally useful only if Numpy tools can't solve the problem. but you can slightly improve your code here since ordered_points as the same elements as range(len(ordered_points)):

```
@jit(nogil=True, nopython=True)
def loop_in_order(ordered_pts, start):
    reverse_index = np.empty_like(ordered_pts)
    prev_pt = np.empty_like(ordered_pts)
    prev = -1
    for i,pt in enumerate(ordered_pts):
        reverse_index[pt] = i
        prev_pt[i] = prev
        prev = pt
    for pt,i in enumerate(reverse_index):
        if start[pt]:
            prev_pt[i] = -1
    return prev_pt
```

Tests with 1000 points:

```
op=np.arange(1000)
np.random.shuffle(op)
ordered_pts=list(op)
start=np.random.randint(0,2,1000,dtype=bool)


In [614]: %timeit loop_in_order(ordered_pts,start)
9.52 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [615]: %timeit numpy_loop_in_order(op,start)
43.6 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [616]: %timeit numba_loop_in_order(op,start)
4.73 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The main improvement is due to the abandonment of `index`.